# ViewArea is shrinking for iOS

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, iphone-x

I have some issues accroding to react-native and my iPhoneX devices. Somehow it just appeared that the ViewArea within my iPhoneX Device has shrinked. It doesn´t fill out the entire display of the device. I actually am not even using the SafeAreaView provided by react-native or react-navigation.

*UPDATE*
Found out that it is related to react-native-splash-screen. Somehow the module might not use SafeArea options.

My environment:

`"react": "16.1.1",
 "react-native": "0.50.3",
 "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.21",
 "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was my bad!!! If you want to realize SplashScreens/Launchmages for Xcode projects then make sure that u have the correct images for your devices. I have missed somehow the iPhoneX resoluted image asset:

[image]

If this missed, the app will be compiled in the next size available and the rootview will be compiled in that size. This caused the empty areas and it is not related to SafeArea.

By the way, i used following module to generate my ressources, its a great tool and makes life so much easier according to Xcode assets: https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/blob/master/generators/assets/README.md